# Tkinter : is there a way to not tab into the widgets behind the raised frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

Theres two widgets both on startpage and pageone and both frames are initialized beforehand.
In my sample code, the tab key cycles to all of the widgets regardless of it being raised or not.
I want to make it so that, when startpage is raised, it only tabcycles through the widgets startpage has

This is my sample code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class AuthApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        frame_list = [StartPage,
                      PageOne
                      ]
        self.title("PageTitle")
        self.geometry("1024x768")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid()
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in frame_list:
            page_name = F.__name__
            print(page_name)
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent,  controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.parent = parent
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="yellow")
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        buttonone = tk.Button(frame, text="Button one", command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        buttontwo = tk.Button(frame, text="Button two")

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        buttonone.grid(row=0, column=1)
        buttontwo.grid(row=0, column=2)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent,  controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.parent = parent
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="yellow")
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        buttonone = tk.Button(frame, text="Button one", command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        buttontwo = tk.Button(frame, text="Button two")

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        buttonone.grid(row=0, column=1)
        buttontwo.grid(row=0, column=2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = AuthApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a fundamental problem with the approach to a multiple-page app that you're using.  Instead of using `.tkraise()`, have `show_frame()` call `.grid()` on the selected frame, and `.grid_forget()` on all the other frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prevent a tabcycle over a button that is there even if you can't see it (when you raise a frame you just put it in front the other but the other still there), however you can, alternatively, ungrid the frame you don't want. Remove the `frame.grid()`and move it to the `show_frame()` method like this:

```
def show_frame(self, page_name):
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

then add a `hide_frame` method:

```
def hide_frame(self, page_name):
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.grid_forget()
```

now, in your Button call both commands:

```
buttonone = tk.Button(frame, text="Button one", command=lambda: [self.controller.hide_frame("StartPage"),self.controller.show_frame("PageOne")])
```

This will guarantee that only the raise framed is in your frame, thus the tabcycle will be only over the buttons you can see.

Just as an additional comment, I don't know if you notice and if is your intention, but the command of the button in the `PageOne` is calling the `PageOne` again and not the `StartPage`.

Comment: thanks for the informative answer! and no it wasn't my intention , i just made the code in like 2 minutes (though most of it came from another answer on stackoverflow) so its a mess. 

I would like to ask another thing though, is grid_forget() destroying the frame? 
like if an entry widget had a text in it before i grid_forget(), would the text be remaining when i re-grid it?

Comment: the grid_forget will not change anything in the frame. The frame will still existing but it will not be placed in the parent. So if you grid it again it will be exactly the same as it was before the grid_forget

Comment: and you can also change the frame before re-gridding it if you want